# DialogFlow Integrations Tap missing

Tags: dialogflow-es

I experience my "Integrations" tap is missing in my DialogFlow agent. See image below:

[Missing "Integrations" tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCyEh.png)

Does anyone know what I have to do in order to get it back? When creating a new agent and assign it to another project it works fine.

Kind Regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon checking the screenshot you've provided, it seems that you're using Europe as the region of your agent. Note that the Integrations feature is not available in the Europe region. For more information, see here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/region#limits.

As a workaround, you may migrate your current agent to the US region by going to Setting > Export and Import > Export as ZIP to export your agent. Then, [create a new agent in the US region](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/region#console), go to Setting > Export and Import > Restore from ZIP to restore your agent.

Here are the detailed steps to migrate your current agent to the US region.

1. Go to agent settings > Export and Import > EXPORT AS ZIP
   [image: EXPORT AS ZIP]
2. Create a new agent in the US region. Make sure to change the region before creating an agent.
   [image: Change region in US]
3. Once you’re in the US region, you can now create a new agent and restore the previously exported agent from the Europe region.
   [image: RESTORE FROM ZIP]

Comment: Great! I simply deleted the agent and created a new one. I wasn't too far ahead. Thank you!